# Get position of rotated div

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, transform

I'm working on a drag and drop div project. In my editor it is possible to resize, position and rotate a selected div. It all works fine as long as the rotation is 0, but once I have set a different rotation, it starts behaving different. I'm not sure exactly what I need to do, but there must be some sort of offset that I need to take into account.

Best example I can provide is: http://recordit.co/0Pskwtrvh0

Notice in the video that without rotation I can move the div around without any problems, but after setting a rotation, everytime I click the div "skips".

Hope someone understands the problem and can push me in the right direction.

Comment: Is position: absolute; for the css?

Comment: @Mikes3ds Yeah, the divs are absolute?

Comment: Post some code to get some more help